# Display pdf/doc/docx from localhost

Tags: html, pdf, ms-word

I need to take `pdf/word` files, which are stored in the  database and display it in view. I have taken all the files now through `query` and the following is my result from the `db`.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'nl_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nl_newsletter' => string 'cbimms learnings.docx' (length=21)

  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'nl_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'nl_newsletter' => string 'Megatrend System Profile.docx' (length=29)

  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'nl_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'nl_newsletter' => string 'Quick Guide.pdf' (length=15)
```

I have no problem to retrieve the `docx/pdf`, but i do not know how to show it in `iframe`. However i tried the following:-

```
<embed src="<?php echo base_url();?>files/cbimms learnings.docx" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

The above code did not display any thing in my `chrome`. when i inspected, there was no `errors` shown.

```
<iframe class="doc" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://writing.engr.psu.edu/workbooks/formal_report_template.doc&embedded=true"></iframe><script>$(".text").fancybox();</script>
```

The above code displayed through the `fancybox`, but i have a doubt whether a file(pdf) located in internet space can only be shown in browser? or our a file(pdf/docx/doc) located in localhost can be shown in browser..?
because, i tried the following:-

```
<iframe class="doc" src="<?php echo base_url();?>files/cbimms learnings.docx"></iframe>
```

The above code did not display any errors but the `docx` file is not displayed.

The following code shows a link which pops up `file`

```
<a class="word" href="//docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.picssel.com/demos/downloads/Fancybox.doc&embedded=true">Open a Word document in Fancybox</a>
```

Can any one guide me a step by step way on how to display/show the `pdf/docx` which are stored in my `db`, to the view(browser).?